# How to get the ID of the new inserted row in the SharePoint list by using web service

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

i am inserting new list items in share point list using web service by using the below code.

```
 ServiceReference.DataContext sc = new ServiceReference.DataContext(new Uri("http://servername:portnumber/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
 sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(spusername, sppassword, spdomain);
 sc.AddToSampleList(new ServiceReference.SampleList
                            {
                                Title= "Hello World"                                                               

                            });
sc.SaveChanges();
```

Its working fine..

I need the ID of the new inserted row..

Is there anyway to get the ID of the newly inserted row just like in costume web part

```
  SPList spList = spWeb.Lists["SampleList"];
  SPListItem spListItem = spList.Items.Add();
  spListItem["Title"] = "Hello world";
  spListItem.Update();
  int ID=spListItem.ID;//like this
```

Any help or suggestions please..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ServiceReference.SampleListItem li = new ServiceReference.SampleListItem { Title= "Hello      World" };
 sc.AddToSampleList(li);
 sc.SaveChanges();
  int id = li.Id;
```

please check the below link for further details

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5750ddc2-a14f-4770-926d-d049a2a6332f/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-new-inserted-row-in-the-sharepoint-list-by-using-web-service?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to change the web service, to return an integer, which would be the ID of the new inserted record. So SaveChanges() would need to return an int. When you do this, you need to update the service reference.

Comment: Dear Stephen, thanks for the reply... the  web service  that i am using was the default web service given by the share point not the custom web service...